# Identify if date is the last date for any given group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that is structured like the below - this contains details about all customer subscriptions and when they start/end.

| SubKey | CustomerID | Status | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29333 | 102 | 7 | 01 jan 2013 | 1 Jan 2014 |
| 29334 | 102 | 6 | 7 Jun 2013 | 15 Jun 2022 |
| 29335 | 144 | 6 | 10 jun 2021 | 17 jun 2022 |
| 29336 | 144 | 2 | 8 oct 2023 | 10 oct 2025 |

I am trying to add an indicator flag to this table (either "yes" or "no") which shows me by each row, if when the [EndDate] of the SubKey is the last one for that CustomerID. So for the above example..

| SubKey | CustomerID | Status | StartDate | EndDate | IsLast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29333 | 102 | 7 | 01 jan 2013 | 1 Jan 2014 | No |
| 29334 | 102 | 6 | 7 Jun 2013 | 15 Jun 2022 | Yes |
| 29335 | 144 | 6 | 10 jun 2021 | 17 jun 2022 | Yes |
| 29336 | 144 | 2 | 8 oct 2023 | 10 oct 2025 | Yes |

The flag is set to No for the first row, because on 1 Jan 2014, customerID 102 had another SubKey (29334) still active at the time (which didn't end until 15 jun 2022)

The rest of the rows are set to "Yes" because these were the last active subscriptions per CustomerID.

I have been reading about the LAG function which may be able to help. I am just not sure how to make it fit in this scenario.

Comment: Subkey 29335 is `Yes` when the same customer also has another subkey not ending until 2025 - this would seem to be `No` by your requirements as explained?

Comment: But at the time 29335 ended(17th June 2022) , the subsequent subscription (29336) hadn’t started… so at the time it was the last one which is what I am trying to indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest method would to use `exists` with a *correlation*. Can you try the following for your desired results for excluding rows without an overlap:

```
select *, 
  case when exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.customerId = t.customerId 
      and t2.enddate > t.enddate 
      and t2.startDate < t.Enddate
  ) then 'No' else 'Yes' end as IsLast
from t;
```